# Creating a Firebase user does not update authStateChanges method

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Quick question. Whenever I create a firebase user with email and password, the routing does not take the user to his correct page.

```
User user = context.watch<User>();
if (user == null) return LoginScreen();
///
    rest of the code here where the user type stored in Firestore decides which page to navigate to
///
```

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` documentation does not say that it updates the authStateChanges method.
On the other hand, `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` documentations clearly states that it updates the authStateChanges method. And when I login the user is indeed taken to the correct page.
I assumed that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` would do the same.

So should I navigate the user to the correct page manually (while popping all previous routes)?

Thank you in advance.

---

Routing Code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final _themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
        Provider<CurrentUser>(create: (context) => CurrentUser()),
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => context.read<CurrentUser>().authStateChanges),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: LandingRouting(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class LandingRouting extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingRouting({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    logger.w('Landing Routing ...');
    User user = context.watch<User>();

    if (user == null) return LoginScreen();

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) return Loading();

        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error loading user'),
            content: Text('${snapshot.error.toString}'),
          );
        else {
          Map<String, dynamic> userData = snapshot.data.data();
          assert(userData['userType'] != null, 'User Type cannot be null');

          if (userData['userType'] == 'baqala') {
            return BaqalaUserScreen();
          } else {
            return UserHomeScreen();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Sign up code:

```
class BaqalaAuth {
  static void registerBaqala({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required String baqalaName,
    @required String license,
    @required String landlineNumber,
    @required String mobileNumber,
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
    @required double lat,
    @required double long,
  }) async {
    try {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then(
        (userCred) async {
          BaqalaInit.initBaqala(
            context: context,
            user: userCred.user,
            landlineNumber: landlineNumber,
            mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
            licenseNumber: license,
            baqalaName: baqalaName,
            lat: lat,
            long: long,
          );
          await userCred.user.updateProfile(displayName: baqalaName);
        },
      );
.
.
.
```

Login Code

```
class Auth {
  static void login({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      logger.i('Login: Firebase Auth Exception');
      _loginException(context, 'Error: ${e.code}\n\n${e.message}');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      logger.i('Login: Firebase Auth Exception');
      _loginException(context, 'Error: ${e.code}\n\n${e.message}');
    } catch (e) {
      _loginException(context, 'Login: Error: ${e.toString}');
    }
  }

  static Future<void> logout() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ```await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()``` awaits its results? and after the result did you call ```notifyListeners()``` to update the state value on your provider?

Comment: From the docs regarding `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`: "The method is a two-step operation; it will first create the new account (if it does not already exist and the password is valid) and then automatically sign in the user in to that account. If you are listening to changes in authentication state, a new event will be sent to your listeners."

Comment: the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method works fine. Once the user logs in or logs out, it navigates them to the correct page. The sign up page does not do that for some reason.

Comment: @lee3 It seems logical that it should update the authStateChanges but it isn't working for me for some reason. I've added the code that handles that should be listening to the status of authentication. This code works for login, logout but not sign up.

Comment: Where do you call `registerBaqala()`? It seems that you are not updating the UI to reflect the state change correctly afterwards.